# What's the best way to maintain endless scroller nodes with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll, redux

If you have a feed like Facebook's, you need to unload posts from your view as the user scrolls. We use an endless scroller that does this. However, this requires us to manage the nodes instead of React, which leads to synchronization problems. Previously, these nodes were Backbone views bound to data changes. However, when there are many posts and only 1 receives a "like", it's important to only rerender the liked post and not the 100s of others in the endless scroller, *especially* on mobile.

What is the best way to keep an endlessly scrolled node (that is relatively detached from its parent component)? The 3 solutions I can think of are...

1. Calculate the data changes in the parent components props (using `prevProps`) and update the necessary child nodes. *However, this performs O(n) deep comparisons.*
2. Use an event bus and have each child node listen to changes that should cause it to rerender. *However, an event bus is a nuance to maintain and gets messy quickly.*
3. Wrap each child node in a new instance of a container and use [reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect) to memoize the props for each child node:

   `let select = reselect.createSelector(state => state.var, var => ({ var }))
   let ReduxChildComponent = ReactRedux.connect(select)(ChildComponent)
   ...
   <Provider store={store}>
   <ReduxChildComponent />
   </Provider>`

   so that the props only trigger a change if they did change. *I'm not sure about how efficient `<Provider>` is when initializing many of them.*

(3) looks like the best solution to me. Does anyone have more light to shed on this?